# Adding variables to response data call in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, axios, concatenation

Is it possible to concatenate variable to a call to response data like so:
res.data.{some_variable}?

I am using axios to call an api, I get a JSON response and in order to get some specific info I have to call each key of the object. The keys are all numbered, "object_1", "object_2", "object_3" and so on. Right now I currently have to call it as many times as the keys are, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

I have tried `res.data.object_${nr}` but that didn't work.

This is my code:

```
const path= "path_to_api";
const object_nr = this.$route.params.nodeID;
axios.get(path)
   .then((res) => {
       this.object_devices = res.data.object_1;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
   });
```

But I would like to be able to add the `object_nr` like so: `res.data.object_{object_nr}`

Comment: Show us a bit more of the code so we have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `const path= 'path_to_api';
      const object_nr = this.$route.params.nodeID;
      axios.get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          this.object_devices = res.data.object_1;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });`

But I would like to be able to put the "object_nr" there instead of "object_1", "object_2", and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get property using index syntax:

```
object['name']
```

So you can build your own index:

```
const foo = 'bar';
object[`name_${foo}`]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem!
Did this:
`const object_nr = this.$route.params.nodeID;
this.object_devices = res.data[\`ip${test}_devices\`];`